# Error : django_migrations.id has unsupported type "serial" with Amazon Redshift

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect my django application with Amazon Redshift.I am using postgres pyscopg2 to connect from django to Redshift. But when i try to do syncdb or start the server, I receive below error

> django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Column "django_migrations.id" has
>   unsupported type "serial".

It seems Serial Datatype is not supported by Redshift. I tried creating a similar table in Redshift with Column `ID` and type as `Integer`.
But it do not resolve the problem

How would I be able to resolve this issue?

Comment: According to the docs, by default Django gives each model an auto-incrementing primary key equivalent to: id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True).

Comment: I found a workaround for this problem. I used a postgres instance as a default DB to manage auth related data in Django settings.py. And added redshift as a second Database for my app related operations. If anyone has better idea, they are most welcome.

Comment: @nijha_p can you explain the steps, how you did that? I am facing same issue and your idea sounds comfy to me as well.... Thanks